# Why does the following code only work with GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layout-manager, grid-layout

When I add `BorderLayout` or `FlowLayout` then I am not able to draw any kind of graphics on `Canvas`. Although it works fine with `GridLayout` but the interface is not so good. 
Even if I try with `setBounds` I get the same result as with border and flow layout. Can anyone give me some suggestions regarding this problem?

```
//Why does the following code not work with FlowLayout??
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Mycanvas1 extends Canvas
{
  int flag=0;
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      g.setColor(Color.pink);
      g.drawRoundRect(30,30,100,100,20,20);
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.drawString("Anks",67,75);
      g.drawOval(100,130,15,15);
      g.drawOval(50,130,15,15);
    }
  }
}
class Myf2 implements ActionListener
{
  Mycanvas1 m=new Mycanvas1();
  Myf2()
  {
    JFrame f=new JFrame("Graphics");
    Button b=new Button("Line");
    //b.setBounds(400,400,41,41);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(m);
    f.add(b);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    m.flag=1;   
    m.repaint();
  }
  public static void main(String... s)
  {
    new Myf2();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: As a tip, when doing custom painting, extend `JPanel` for the initial attempts.  A `JPanel` is 1) Swing. 2) Double buffered by default. 3) Plenty fast enough for simple animations. -- If you really need high rendering rates for a game, I'd strongly recommend either Full Screen Exclusive mode or a Game Engine (which might use FSE mode).  Writing fast rendering code is an art and a science, best not attempted by a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't let the `Canvas` to have a size then this may cause problems depending on the `Layout`.

`FlowLayout` does not resize its subcomponents, it just let them determine their own size (default 0,0 for `Canvas`) and place them in the space of the `Container` from left to right and then top to bottom.

`BorderLayout` resizes the subcomponents but you need to use the `BorderLayout` constraints: `NORTH`, etc. The default constraints is `CENTER` but it is wrong to add two components in the same `BorderLayout`'s logical space.

`GridLayout` resizes its components in such a way that every component have the same size (a rectangle), they are placed in a logical grid, etc. And the logical grid fills all the space of its `Container` host.

So, add a `Dimension getPreferredSize()` method to your component that returns the "natural" size of your drawing inside. This will let your component behave much more normally.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mycanvas1 extends Canvas
```

AFAIR a `Canvas` has a default size of 0x0 pixels.  `@Override` the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a sensible value that *might* be honored by the layout.

Here's what I mean, using `FlowLayout`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Mycanvas1 extends Canvas {

    int flag = 0;

    Mycanvas1() {
        // so we can easily see its bounds
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); // honor the paint chain..
        if (flag == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.drawRoundRect(30, 30, 100, 100, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawString("Anks", 67, 75);
            g.drawOval(100, 130, 15, 15);
            g.drawOval(50, 130, 15, 15);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(150,150);
    }
}

class Myf2 implements ActionListener {

    Mycanvas1 m = new Mycanvas1();

    Myf2() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Graphics");
        // best done before adding components
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        Button b = new Button("Line");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.add(m);
        f.add(b);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //f.setSize(400, 400); // no, don't guess, instead..
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        m.flag = 1;
        m.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new Myf2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Myf2()
{
JFrame f=new JFrame("Graphics");
Button b=new Button("Line");
b.setBounds(400,400,41,41);
b.addActionListener(this);
f.add(m);
f.add(b);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);
}